# Do I need different version of mysql-connector for jdk 8

Tags: java-8, executable-jar, mysql-connector

I'm using mysql-connector-java-5.1.6-bin with jdk 6 currently but I'm moving my project to jdk 8 do I need to download different version of this jar file?

Answer (score 2):

If you want use JDK 8, you need the latest version of mysql connector,  Connector/J 8.0

From the [*What's New in Connector/J 8.0?* page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-whats-new.html):

> - It is a MySQL driver for the Java 8 platform. For Java 7 or earlier, use Connector/J 5.1 instead.

Comment: Oh.. you were faster than me.

Comment: Note that you don't *need* Connector/J 8, but you *can* use it you don't need to support earlier Java versions in your product. The Connector/J 5.1 supports Java 6, 7 and 8. The Connector/J 8 supports Java 8 only. Also, Interestingly, neither mentions supporting Java 9 or 10 yet... https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-versions.html

Answer (score 1):

You don't require Connector/J 8.0 to run on JRE 8. Connector/J 5.1 works too but 5.1 is getting much less maintenance effort these days.

Connector/J 5.1 works with JRE 1.5 and above, at least until Java breaks compatibility with these older bytecodes.

Connector/J 8.0 works with JRE 8.0 and above.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-versions.html