# which version of Connector/J should I choose for java 13.0.1, mysql 5.7?

Tags: java, mysql, mysql-connector

this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48005922/12492163) says

> If you want use JDK 8, you need the latest version of mysql connector, Connector/J 8.0

I am using java 13.0.1, mysql 5.7, when I tried install Connector/J, 8.x is disabled.

[image]

which version should I choose?

Comment: You don't need to install Connector/J. It's just a jar file, that must be in the dependencies (i.e. the runtime classpath) of your application. Get it from where you probably get all your other opensource dependencies: Maven central. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for your comments. I am using java 13.0.1, mysql 5.7. Should I choose the latest (8.0.18) MySQL Connector/J in from mvnrepository?

Comment: I guess so, yes. I don't use MySQL. What does the documentation say?

Comment: According to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-versions.html, Connector/J 8.x requires "Java 8 or later".  Thus, any version of Connect/J 8.x would be compatible with Java 13 ... modulo possible bugs.  (Check the release notes if you are concerned.)

Comment: The other thing to note is that Oracle owns MySQL, so you would expect that there would be some internal coordination to ensure that Connector/J supports the latest Java version.

Answer (score 0):

You may use Connector/J 5.1 or Connector/J 8.0 but mind that 5.1 is not getting that much maintenance efforts these days.

Connector/J 8.0 requires at least Java 8 while Connector/J 5.1 requires at least Java 5. See all details in the [Connector/J documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-versions.html)

The grayed options in the windows installer looks like a bug. Please report it in [MySQL Bugs](https://bugs.mysql.com/) if you want.

As @JBNizet replied, you don't need to actually install Connector/J. Just obtain the Jar from any of the [official download site](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) or [central maven](https://search.maven.org/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java) and place it somewhere in your application's dependencies (in some directory pointed in the runtime classpath or use some building tool for the effect).

If you like you can also build it from the [source code](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-j) following these [instructions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-installing-source.html). This is particularly useful if you need to do some deeper debugging and tests.